# Extracting data similar to the output of xxd from binary files

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles, xxd

I have a binary file that represents the output of a sensor.
On my bash-terminal I can show the data of the file using `xxd -b atis.es` which results in an output like this:

> 00000000: 01000101 01110110 01100101 01101110 01110100 00100000 Event
>   00000006: 01010011 01110100 01110010 01100101 01100001 01101101 Stream
>   0000000c: 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000010 01000000 00000001 ....@.
>   00000012: 11110000 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 11101111 ......

Now I am trying to import this file in my C++ code, but I'm struggling to understand how this works.
The file that I'm experementing on, can be found [here](https://github.com/neuromorphic-paris/event_stream) with the corresponding explanation of the Byte-Structure. As far as I understand the explanation (I never worked with Binary files before) the first 19 Bytes are just a Header, so the data is written in Byte 20 and following. So in C++ I used this code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::ifstream data;
  data.open("path-to-file/atis.es", std::ios::binary);

  std::cout<<data.tellg()<<'\n'; % check current position
  data.seekg(20); % jump to 20th byte
  char buffer[100];
  data.read(buffer,100);
  std::cout<<buffer<<std::endl;
}
```

From this code I would expect that it outputs `0` first, because `tellg()` should return 0 as position as long as I didn't do anything with the fsteam, or not? After that I would expect the code to output the first 100 characters after the 20th byte. I'm not sure, if `seekg(20)` actually jumps to the 20th byte though and I couldn't figure it out reading about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).
The output I actually get is `-1` and some strange triangular character.
Ultimately my target is to store the data of the file in an `array` or `struct` with the fields `t`, `x`, `y`, `pol`. But I guess I can figure that out on my own, as soon as I understood a little bit more about how to use and work with the binary files.
Something that I would like to know additionally is why `xxd` outputs the header of the file broken down into multiple lines after the 6 Bytes each instead of just putting it before the data.

Comment: Is the data at position `20` (decimal) in the file a *null-terminated string* of at most 99 characters (plus terminator)? If not then you can't output it using `std::cout << buffer`.

Comment: Are you certain the read was successful?  You are not checking the stream for errors, and you are reading into an uninitialized buffer.  That's asking for trouble.